# Problem with reading and writing to a file at the same time

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to read and write the file at the same time in C. I can write to the file but couldn't read from the file. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = "C programming language";
    char str1[100];
    FILE *fptr = fopen("Output.txt", "r+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        printf("Could not open file!");
    fputs(str, fptr);

    fgets(str1,100,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

**Please assume that the output.txt file already exists on my computer.**

Comment: Generally more trouble than it is worth. Consider if you actually want to use a file for what you should be using memory for.

Comment: The code needs to call `fflush()` on the file descriptor between the `write()` and the `read()` so the file will be 'up-to-date'

Comment: regarding: `printf("Could not open file!");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  3) the function: `perror()` properly handles #1 and #2.  4) the file is NOT open so must not continue executing the code, as if the file were open.  Should call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(str1,100,fptr);`  Should always check the returned value, if it is NULL, then the operation failed.  so should not continue executing the code, as if the call to `fgets()` were successful

Comment: regarding: `fputs(str, fptr);

    fgets(str1,100,fptr);`  After the call to `fputs()` the 'file pointer' will be past the location that contains the just written data.  So need to use `fseek()` to move the 'file pointer' back to the beginning of that just written data.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen:

> For files open for update (those which include a "+" sign), on which
>   both input and output operations are allowed, the stream shall be
>   flushed (fflush) or repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) before a
>   reading operation that follows a writing operation. The stream shall
>   be repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) before a writing operation
>   that follows a reading operation (whenever that operation did not
>   reach the end-of-file).

Answer (score 1):

After you've done the write, you should seek to beginning of the file. For that call rewind().

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = "C programming language";
    char str1[100];
    FILE *fptr = fopen("Output.txt", "r+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        printf("Could not open file!");
    fputs(str, fptr);

    rewind(fptr); // seek to beginning

    fgets(str1,100,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-position the offset to beginning to read that string.

After your write, the pointer is at the offset which is past the string your wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = "C programming language";
    char str1[100];
    FILE *fptr = fopen("Output.txt", "r+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        printf("Could not open file!");
    fputs(str, fptr);

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET); // add this
    fgets(str1,100,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}

./main.out
C programming language
```